# Notifications - when to use success and when info

Tags: notification, software

Currently, we have implemented notifications to the software and I started to get puzzled when to use success and when to use info notification.

Ie. Forgot password - Notification: Password has been sent - is its success or info?
save view - Notification: View has been saved (this is success right?)

Can someone explain to me how to use them properly?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to distinguish between the two? Is there any difference for the user? Do they have to do something in one case; is it logged somewhere in one case and not in the other?
If there is none, then in the interest of KISS (Keep It Small and Simple) I'd omit the success notification and just use "Info". If you are confused, users may be as well and wonder about the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

**Success** notification makes sense when you were not sure in success. Usual things don't need to respond with success every time.

Example: I wake up in the morning and open my eyes. Is it a **success**? Well, yes, in some sense. But I do this every day without thinking about it.